# Two Java classes in the same view

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-view

I am new to Android and Java Programming and I want to ask if its possible one r.layout View to "hold" two or more different classes. I'v tried to put the same r.layout.id in both constructors but it seems that the second class call creates a second instance of the View. 
Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking; a layout can have multiple views.

Comment: I want two classes to run on the same View. e.g class foobar1 extends Activity and uses R.layout.main and class foobar2 extends another activity and use also R.layout.main

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Activities uses layouts. Layout themselves have no idea about which activity is using them. So yes you can have one `main.xml` layout which can be used by two different activities' `setContentView`. But both Activities will have separate instance of layouts in-memory.

Comment: Hi, I have one activity which uses chronometer to displays Real time and a Second activity which uses GPS (LocationManager). I want in the same layout.view to display real time from chronometer and at the same time to get GPS data.When I start the GPS activity it creates a second instance of the layout.main view :-(. Is it possible to avoid that ? Thanks again

Comment: In this case you should have only one activity and one layout. The update of view logic should be done on a background thread like AsyncTask.

Comment: Thank you , it seems complex for my level :-) but I ll try to do it